# ERROR @wdio/config:ConfigParser: Failed loading configuration file

Tags: typescript, automation, package.json, webdriver-io, wdio

Issue occurred after updating WebDriverIo to 8. Happens when I try to execute tests.

Here is the complete error message:

```
   Failed loading configuration file: file:///Users/xxx/project.conf.ts: Package subpath './build/utils/SevereServiceError' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/xxx/project/node_modules/webdriverio/package.json
    Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './build/utils/SevereServiceError' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/xxx/project/node_modules/webdriverio/package.json
```

Does anyone have an idea what might be the issue here?
There are no "require" but only "import .. from" which is ok for wdio v8.

The problem seems to be with here:

```
import SevereServiceError from "webdriverio/build/utils/SevereServiceError";
```